# Animated Image Caption in asp.net webform page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working on asp.net based Photo gallery & i display image in as a Matrix, I am using following article to implement animated Image caption for of of these image

http://buildinternet.com/2009/03/sliding-boxes-and-captions-with-jquery/

It is working fine except that i want to show the image caption on move over & hide the caption on mouse out function.

I tried to alter the script but i am not able to make it work

I have uploaded my script on http://jsfiddle.net/AMcnZ/12/

Help in this regard in appreciated. Yesterday i tried several Image caption script some of them where really cool but non of them worked in asp.net for some reason..

I have got this one working but i am not able to modify the script to implement the effects similar to first example show on the link http://www.wbotelhos.com/capty/

I tried this example but could not get it working for some reason on asp.net webform. I would appreciate if some can fix my script on  http://jsfiddle.net/AMcnZ/12/ to get the desired effect as show in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle with the correct behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/kayen/JBnbG/

Since you are displaying the caption at the bottom of the page, you need to alter the animate **bottom** property and set it to **0** on hover and **(0 - height of caption)px** on mouse out.